# How to emulate window.location with react-router and ES6 classes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router, so I use the `<Link />` component for my links throughout the app, in some cases I need to dynamically generate the link based on user input, so I need something like  `window.location`, but without the page refresh.

I found this little note - (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/835) - i tried using `this.context.router.transitionTo(mylink)` but I'm having issues with context...

which led me to (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1059), however context returns and empty object, so when I try todo something like: `this.context.router.transitionTo(mylink);` I get `Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined` (if I try to do something like set this.context = context within the constructor).

Not to drag on, but I'm also weary of messing too much with context as it is undocumented on purpose as it's still a work in progress, so I've read.

Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/975, and here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1499

Needed in constructor:

```
class SidebarFilter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
```

Also need to add a static property:

```
SidebarFilter.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Then I could call:

```
this.context.router.transitionTo(/path-to-link);
```

Answer (score 31):

After wasting time with react router, I finally switch to basic javascript.

1. Create a component for your redirect:

   Route path="*" component={NotFound}
2. In the component use window.location to redirect:

   ```
    componentDidMount() {
         if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
              window.location.href = "http://foo.com/error.php";
         }
    }
   ```

Comment: the question is tagged react-router -- if you are advocating not using that tool you should give a detailed explanation about why it won't work

Comment: Don’t fall into the [trap of thinking a library should prescribe how to do everything](http://amasad.me/2016/01/03/overcoming-intuition-in-programming/). If you want to do something with a location in JavaScript, you can use window.location. There is no reason why react-outer should be any different.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using browserHistory for React-router, life is simpler.

```
import {browserHistory} from "react-router";

functionName() {
 browserHistory.push("/path-to-link");
}
```

Comment: Error: 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.

Comment: The way to use browserHistory has changed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822589/react-router-v4-browserhistory-is-undefined

Answer (score 3):

Use `Link` from `react-router-dom`, in my snippet I was using the `material-ui <Button>`

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
    
<Button color="primary" 
to="/join" component={Link}>
Join a Room
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `Navigation` mixin from react-router. http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Navigation

From the docs:

```js
var Navigation = require('react-router').Navigation;

React.createClass({
  mixins: [Navigation],

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.transitionTo('foo')}>Go to foo</div>
      <div onClick={() => this.replaceWith('bar')}>Go to bar without creating a new history entry</div>
      <div onClick={() => this.goBack()}>Go back</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @paulshen. Unfortunately I'm using ES6 classes, so I can't use mixins. I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'm trying to import the Navigation method, e.g. `import {Navigation} from 'react-router'`... trying to see if that's possible, running into some issues with `this.context` within the transitionTo that I'm trying to figure out now.

Answer (score 2):

In such a situation i normally use `hashHistory` or `browserHistory` depending on what you are using and simply call `hashHistory.push(<url>)`. If you are using ES6 classes you can also go for the `withRouter` Hoc provided by react-router as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options). This higher order component exposes a prop in your component called `router`. Using this prop you can redirect using `this.props.router.push(<url>)`.

If you have to use the router from the context you will have to provide the context types as mentioned in @Ben's answer.

Comment: the link is broken, I came across a similar problem today, is there any better solution available now?

Answer (score 2):

Use `useHistory` to get the history object and push to it to change the url

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ModificarUsuario({ url }) {
  const history = useHistory();
  
  function newRoute(){
    history.push('/my-route')
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your short code snipped and how it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to use useHistory from react-router-dom.
First you have to import it :

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then , you have to declare an instance of it by doing this :

```
  let history = useHistory();
```

then inside an arrow function or whatever are your case do this :

```
history.push("Type here your route link not a domain not anythins else ... .")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I ended up having to do this (I think I'm running an older version of react 16.14.0, react-router, react-router-dom, and history 5.3.0 and other dependencies for compatibility reasons):

```
import (createBrowserHistory) from 'history';

const broswerHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const SomeFunction = props => {
   browserHistory.push('Thepath');
   browserHistory.go('SamePath');
}
```

The push by itself just put the path into the browser address bar without going there. The go by itself just reloaded the current page.

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to avoid reloading:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: `/page/${id}/something`
})
```