# react-router v4 - browserHistory is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

I am creating my first react app in electron (my first electron app too). I have two routes & need to navigate from one to another. For that I am using following code:

**Root**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-master">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/city' component={CityList}/>
                    <Route path='/' component={SplashScreen}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
...
browserHistory.push('/city');
```

This line gives error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I searched web for possible solution but can't find one! There are many similar questions on SO too, but none of it worked for me :(

Comment: because you're not doing anything special in your `App` constructor, this part is unnecessary:
`
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to import it from the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) module now which provides 3 different methods to create different histories.

- `createBrowserHistory` is for use in modern web browsers that support the [history API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=history)
- `createMemoryHistory` is used as a reference implementation and may also be used in non-DOM environments, like React Native or tests
- `createHashHistory` for legacy web browsers

You cannot use the browser history in an electron environment, use the hash or the memory one.

```js
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'

const history = createHashHistory()
```

You can then use the `history` injected in the props

```
this.props.history.push('/')
```

Comment: Its do not give error now, but page is not changed :(

Comment: Are you using the `Router` from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Can you put the `Router` in the `App` rather than in the root file and right on top of your `Switch`? I think it needs to be a direct children

Comment: did that, just cut-pasted `Switch` in root, still no change :(

Comment: I would do the opposite, move `Router` and now `Switch` to the `App`

Comment: Sorry, but I used in electron `this.props.location.pathname` & its returning 'index.html', this might be issue I think.

Comment: How are you serving your app? If you just opened an `index.html` file, yes it's the issue. You can't manipulate history of the `file://` protocol.

Comment: I am using webpack to build final files & doing `electron .` to fire the app.

Comment: Ok, can you try using a hash or memory history instead then? `createMemoryHistory ` or `createHashHistory`

Comment: I already tried `createHashHistory`, after your comment tried `createMemoryHistory`, nothing works! Reseaching on react router in electron app!

Comment: Finally I managed to find solution! `this.props.history.push('/city');` combined with `createHashHistory`. Thanks for all help! I'll add a seperat answer to anyone who get this issue in future!

Comment: Thanks saved me lot of typing :D

Comment: I logged my this.props.history and found a method called goBack(). Then it worked pretty well for me: redirect back to where I was when clicking the "login", after successfully login. Hope this helps.

Comment: @demonofthemist, Can you perhaps put your answer here I have similar problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: @MarkAndog I used createHashHistory just like above. Balthazar comments helped me and he also updated his answer, please refer above only.

Comment: @demonofthemist, I'm doing this in a function so I can't access the `this.props.history.push().` So what i did is `const hashHistory = createHashHistory()` and used `hashHistory.push("/");`

Comment: @MarkAndog Pardon but It looks like different case, also this question is quite old. I’ll suggest you post a new question, it will be more helpful.

Comment: @demonofthemist, Yea okay I posted it now.

Answer (score 4):

Useful pointers above. The simplest solution I've found is to add:

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
```

to your list of import statements, then add:

```
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
```

Might not work perfectly, but for the basic stuff I'm working on seems to do the trick. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Its is not working for your because in your component you are still using `browserHistory` which is not longer availabe from `react-router` package. You should change to using history from the `history` package

To simplify you can create a history.js file with the following contents

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Root

```
import history from '/path/to/history';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
      <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Page

```
import history from 'path/to/history';
...
history.push('/city');
```

Comment: No I did changed in my component too, its still not working. No error is there now, but view is same!

Comment: Is the route changing

Comment: God these packages have terrible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` does not work in React router 4. [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732)

Use the redirect component:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
<Redirect push to="/somewhere/else"/>
```

The render function should replace the entire content with Redirect component.

Comment: For the above code i am getting error `Uncaught Error: You should not use outside a Redirect outside the Router`

Answer (score 0):

In react-router v4 initialize router as constant config and access the history through `this.props` in child components.

#### Import you dependecies

```
import { Route, Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
```

### Define your router config and add history as prop

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/city' component={CityList}/>
    <Route path='/' component={SplashScreen}/>
  </Router> )

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div className = "app-master> 
      {routes} 
    </div>)
}
```

Defining route as a constant and out of render method this would initialize the route config only once.

### Page Component

```
class Page extend Component {
  render() {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }
}
```

The history is now available as props in all the child components defined in routes config.