# What can I use instead of browserHistory in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What can I use instead of browserHistory in react js?

I have a method like below in index.js file

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
        console.log('user has signed in or up', user);
    } else {
        console.log('user signed out or still need to sign in', user);
    }
})
```

I past I can use browserHistory.push to redirect login user and logout user browserHistory.replace like that, how can I do that now

> react-router-dom' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'.

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822589/react-router-v4-browserhistory-is-undefined

Comment: Im new If u know please help me