# React-router - Hook useHistory Error: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use the hook useHistory from [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) of [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

I keep getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Here an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-meadow-bwnt8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
     <HomeButton />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: post your route configuration file

Comment: Was able to solve whith this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822589/react-router-v4-browserhistory-is-undefined

Answer (score 4):

The `useHistory` hook only works inside of a Route.

It is the route that passes the history object to the `useHistory` hook. Which is why in this case it is undefined - there is no route to pass the history object to it.