# replacement of window.location in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react and react-router do we have any replacement of window.location.assign or any other window method for redirection in react or react-router? I want to redirect to some other website. Not on the same react website from which I am redirecting.
I found this answer [How to emulate window.location with react-router and ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539349/how-to-emulate-window-location-with-react-router-and-es6-classes) but it is redirecting to some other page in the react application only so, this is not sufficient for me.

I am using react-router v4+

Comment: use `Redirect` import from `react-router-dom`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: This is not possible with react-router 4.0

Comment: @Raviteja I tried Redirect method but that is not working because I am not redirecting to any page of my react application and redirecting to an external page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried using the history package, after installing history package,

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();
history.push('www.abc.com');
history.go(0);
```

Comment: I don't want to use any other package for that, Thanks, btw!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to redirect third party URLs

```
location.assign(<Your URL>);
```

example:

```
location.assign("https://google.com")
```