# react router redirect to self/same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to redirect in react router in self page. e.g I have a component `ProfileUpdate` it updates name & stores to backend. After successful update I want to redirect to same page but it's not working. Here is a sample code.

```
class ProfileUpdate extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            name: ''
        };
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.replace('/');    
  }

  onChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({
      name
    }))
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <h4>Display Name:</h4>
                    <div>
                        <input name='displayName' placeholder='Display name' type='text' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type='submit'>Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Expected behaviour if I update name then click submit it will replace the route/redirect & name input should be empty.

But when I choose a different path to replace it works. e.g `this.props.history.replace('/users')` it works. But here `this.props.history.replace('/');` it doesn't work.

Comment: window.location.reload()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539349/how-to-emulate-window-location-with-react-router-and-es6-classes/31553732#31553732

Comment: @JayakumarThangavel thanks for your comment but if I use `window.location.reload()` it will be reload not redirect & if I use `window.location.href` won't in both cases it will be full page refresh, As we are using react router I guess this should be my last choice. However thanks once again.